# Round Robin (Scheduling) Algorithm with I/O

Tags: operating-system, cpu, round-robin

Can someone please explain and give me example of Round Robin (Scheduling) Algorithm with I/O?

Like explanation with gantt chart.

Answer (score 0):

In Round Robin scheduling algorithm, Each process gets a small unit of CPU time (time quantum), usually 10-100 milliseconds. After this time has elapsed, the process is preempted and added to the end of the ready queue.

If there are n processes in the ready queue and the time quantum is q, then each process gets 1/n of the CPU time in chunks of at most q time units at once. No process waits more than (n-1)q time units.

A tabular example is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling). Also refer [this link at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Round-robin_schedule_quantum_3.png) for a well represented gantt chart like example.

Comment: thanks but i learned simple round robin. i just want to learn round robin with input output interrupts.